# Adding conditions for URLSearchParams in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a table that calls the following function to fetch data.

```
export function fetchAddressRecords(itemsPerPage,page,sortBy,orderBy,query) {
  let p = new URLSearchParams();
  p.append("pageSize", itemsPerPage || 10);
  p.append("pageNumber", page || 1);
  p.append("keySelector", sortBy || "addressId");
  p.append("orderBy", orderBy || "asc");
  p.append("query", query || "");

  return fetch("http://localhost:6505/api/v1/address?" + p).then(
   response => response.json(),
  );
}
```

At the moment the URL for the fetched data returns`http://localhost:6505/api/v1/address?pageSize=10&pageNumber=1&keySelector=addressId&orderBy=asc&query=`

What i would like to do, is only append the 'query' parameter if it has a value. So  the URL returned would be `http://localhost:6505/api/v1/address?pageSize=10&pageNumber=1&keySelector=addressId&orderBy=asc`but if someone typed into the searchbox, then the url would include the 'query' again.

Is this possible? Or would i always need to show an empty 'query' to start with? Would this affect the way that the api fetches the data?

Comment: let should be const

Comment: *"Would this affect the way that the api fetches"* ... we have no way to know what is required and what's not. Simple enough for you to test yourself in browser address bar  or using rest client tool like Postman

Comment: Thanks @Jin i'll get that changed.

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl, i'll have a look into using Postman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a short-cut conditional, so you only append a `query` if there is one:

```
export function fetchAddressRecords(itemsPerPage,page,sortBy,orderBy,query) {
  let p = new URLSearchParams();
  p.append("pageSize", itemsPerPage || 10);
  p.append("pageNumber", page || 1);
  p.append("keySelector", sortBy || "addressId");
  p.append("orderBy", orderBy || "asc");
  query && p.append("query", query);

  return fetch("http://localhost:6505/api/v1/address?" + p).then(
   response => response.json(),
  );
}
```

To explain, values in js are 'truthy', which means they can be treated like a boolean will resolve to true or false. In your case, query is either a string, which evaluates to true, or undefined, which evaluates to false when evaluated as a boolean.

So it's:

```
query &&  p.append("query", query);
```

which becomes is either:

```
false && [does not get evaluated]
```

or

```
true && [does get evaluated, which means that p.append is called)
```

You do have to be *slightly* careful with using `&&` as a shortcut like this, because e.g. the number 0 evaluates as false, even though it is 'defined'. However, in your case, as long as you have a string it will evaluate to `true`:

```
false && true //false
0 && true // false
"0" && true // true
"false" && true // true
```

Comment: Then what is the purpose of `||`?

Comment: @WillJenkins thanks so much for your help yesterday, could you explain what the new line of code is doing? I just assumed it was if 'query' exists then append 'query' but the && is throwing me off.

Comment: have added more explanation - does that help?